# How to register an existing Clearcase view existing on other server

Tags: unix, clearcase

I have a two views of the same name on two different servers but they are not synchronized.
They do not have the same config spec as shown below.
Environment is AIX.

```
t123456@server1:/dwp_root/d/streams/rcl/bin:d> ct catcs -tag deliver_pml_ux
element * A46_1.4.2

t123456@server2:/u/t123456:t> ct catcs -tag deliver_pml_ux
element * DEM_7.7.52
```

Information from server 1

```
t123456@server1:/u/t123456:d> ct lsview -l -pro -full deliver_pml_ux
Tag: deliver_pml_ux
  Global path: /clearcase/views/deliver_pml_ux.vws
  Server host: server1
  Region: dwh
  Active: YES
  View tag uuid:58a2fc3c.761011e8.8052.00:02:c7:d6:16:4c
View on host: server1
View server access path: /clearcase/views/deliver_pml_ux.vws
View uuid: 58a2fc3c.761011e8.8052.00:02:c7:d6:16:4c
View owner: ccadmin


t123456@server1:/u/t123456:d>ct lsstgloc -view -long 
Name: viewstg
  Type: View
  Region: dwh
  Storage Location uuid: 3a407c2c.ca8b11e1.805a.00:02:f6:0b:ad:4c
  Global path: /clearcase/stg/views
  Server host: d1dw753
  Server host path: /clearcase/stg/views
```

Information from server 2

```
t123456@server2:/u/t123456:t> ct lsview -l -pro -full deliver_pml_ux
Tag: deliver_pml_ux
  Global path: /clearcase/views/deliver_pml_ux.vws
  Server host: server2
  Region: dwh
  Active: YES
  View tag uuid:9c721b34.ba1811e1.8026.00:02:f6:0b:ad:4c
View on host: server2
View server access path: /clearcase/views/deliver_pml_ux.vws
View uuid: 9c721b34.ba1811e1.8026.00:02:f6:0b:ad:4c
View owner: loaddsfr


t123456@server2:/u/t123456:t> ct lsstgloc -view -long 
t123456@server2:/u/t123456:t>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you need to use [`cleartool register`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_register.htm) in your case.

```
ct register -view -replace -host server2 -hpath /clearcase/views/deliver_pml_ux.vws /clearcase/views/deliver_pml_ux.vws
```

It needs to run on a ClearCase client within the right target region.

Comment: I have 2 views with the same name one server1 and server2.

Comment: I have 2 views with the same name but with different config spec and different contents. And I would like to have a same view (it means same content) visible from server 1 and server 2.

Comment: Same content means simply the same config spec: compare the output of `cleartool catcs` executed on the view in server1 and in view on server2

Comment: Would it be possible to modify one of them and that the other be modified too.

Comment: @pindare If by "modify", you mean the config spec (selection rules) then no, unless they share the very same global path for a view storage. But if by "modified" you mean checkout/checkin files, then yes: if the config spec is the same, the views will display the same content (after checkin).